# ERROR: While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)

Tags: grails, sass, asset-pipeline

Using Grails 2.4.5 and:

```
compile ":asset-pipeline:2.5.1"
provided ":sass-asset-pipeline:2.3.1"
```

When I do `grails prod war` I get the following error:

```
|Processing File 163 of 516 - admin/login.scssERROR:  Loading command: install (LoadError)
    load error: jopenssl/load -- java.lang.VerifyError: class org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Primitive overrides final method equals.(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

This error occurs even if the file is empty

**How do I fix this error?**